# MinGW application does not accept any user input

Tags: mingw, stdin

- MinGW2 i686 20190524
- Windows 10 1803 Build 17134

I clean installed MinGW2 on my Windows 10 PC, and run the next command on 32bit console, to make p11tool available.

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gnutls
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-libtasn1
```

Then I run p11tool. It is a tool to access HSM device. During a process, it asks user to enter a password.

The problem is that the console cannot pass the user input to the application apparently. The application does not respond.

When I terminate the application with CTRL+C, interestingly, the data I inputted appears after terminating the app, then it is treated as another user input for the command prompt.

```
user@pc MINGW32 /c/cst
$ p11tool --super-duper-long-options
Enter password: password
(p11tool was terminated with CTRL+C)

user@pc MINGW32 /c/cst
$ password
bash: password: command not found
```

I have no clue what is going on and how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `p11tool` is calling something underlying to process your console input.
Maybe you can avoid the console typing and use redirection instead?

```
echo "MYTOPSECRETPASSWORD"|p11tool --super-duper-long-options
```